# Irreducible over the rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $x^2-4x+2$ is irreducible over the rationals.

I know I must use Eisenstein's criterion but I don't know how to apply it here.

Comment: You know that the Rational Root Theorem is enough. For Eisenstein, let $p=2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eisenstein's criterion is directly applicable with $p = 2$.

---

For an alternative proof, it suffices to show that (since the degree of the polynomial is $2$) that there are no rational roots. This can be done with the rational roots theorem, or by noting that the polynomial splits over $\mathbb{R}$, and its roots are

$$\frac{4 \pm \sqrt{8}}{2} = 2 \pm \sqrt 2$$

Neither is rational.

Comment: I just learned Eisenstein criterion a few moments ago but my book didn't show any examples on how to use it. So from Eisenstein I can use $p=2$ which divides $(2-4x)$ but it does not divide $x^2$. And hence I am done? Is that how we use Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: @Alex Pretty much. The only other thing to check is that $2^2$ doesn't divide the constant term.

Comment: What if I have a complicated example where it is not so obvious to find $p$? Like $x^4-24x^2+4$. Here $p^2$ does divide the constant term. What should I do then?

Comment: @Alex In that case, Eisenstein isn't directly applicable. But it *is* quadratic in $x^2$, and $t^2 - 24t + 4$ can be solved directly.

Comment: Last question, the constant term in $x^2-4x+2$ is $2$ so for our choice of $p$ we have $p^2 = 2^2$ which does divide the constant. Why were we able to use here?

Comment: @Alex $4$ is not a divisor of $2$.

Comment: Oh I see now. I was getting it backwards because 2 is a divisor of 4. I will go over the site for other questions related to this so I can have a better grasp. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Alex You're very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we need a prime $p$ that divides $-4$ and $2$, but does not divide $1$, and such that $p^2$ does not divide $2.$ Can you think of any such primes?

Comment: I just learned Eisenstein criterion a few moments ago but my book didn't show any examples on how to use it. So I don't really know how to apply it correctly. But from using your hint, I can use p=2 which divides (2−4x) but it does not divide x2. And hence I am done? Is that how we use Eisenstein's criterion

Comment: Yep! That is exactly how it is done.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Eisenstein Criterion: 
Suppose we have the following polynomial with integer coefficients.

$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0\,$
If there exists a prime number p such that the following three conditions all apply:

p divides each $a_i$ for i ≠ n,
p does not divide $a_n$, and
$p^2$ does not divide $a_0$,

2 is prime and divides $a_0$(in this case 2) but $2^2$ not divide $a_0$  and $a_1$ (in this case -4) but no
$a_2$ (in this case 1). So, this polynomial is irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

Both Eisenstein and the Rational Root Test are overkill. We can prove it just like we prove the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}.\,$ If $\,a/b\,$ is a root in lowest terms then $\, 0 = b^2 f(a/b) = a^2-4ab+2b^2\,$ thus $\,2\mid a^2\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{2\mid a}\,\Rightarrow\,4\mid a^2\,\Rightarrow\,4\mid 2b^2\,\Rightarrow\,2\mid b^2\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{2\mid b},\,$ contra $\,a/b\,$ in lowest terms.

**Remark** $\ $ This is essentially equivalent to the irrationality proof of $\sqrt{2},\,$ since this polynomial has discriminant $= 8,\,$ and $\,\sqrt{8} = 2\sqrt 2.$